# How to compare last modified time of a file in ansible

Tags: time, ansible

I have a file with last modified time shown as "1563886751.38" (with stat and mtime). I wanted to check if the time is same when I run the playbook.

I have defined a variable as file_time: 1563872351.
I wanted to check if this value is present in the mtime.

```
vars: 
file_date: 1563872351

- name: test
    stat:
     path: /tmp/logrotate/testx1
    register: sym

- debug:
   msg: "{{same}}"
  when: sym.stat.mtime.find(file_date) != -1
```

But I get the below error:

```
'dict object' has no attribute 'find'
```

I see there is not attribute find but is there some way to do this? I need to check if it contains the value, not equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by converting both values to strings and using the `in` operator:

```
    - debug:
        msg: same
      when: file_date|string in sym.stat.mtime|string
```

I don't know exactly what you would use that for, but perhaps this would be a better approach for you:

```
    - debug:
        msg: same
      when: sym.stat.mtime|int == file_date
```

Comment: Thanks, if they are not same I need to print the last modified time. If i print it is in float, do you know how to print in date format.

Comment: Yeah try this to convert from epoch to date string: `{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(sym.stat.mtime) }}` - you can play with the formatting as needed